# Wrapping title is not working

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, word-wrap

We have a need to include long title for Sharepoint's (2007) built in webpart. title runs across and users are having to scroll left to right. Is there a way to introduce wrapping to the web part title? I tried few html tag but they are not working.

Comment: What is the title that you have for your web part?

Answer (score 3):

You should add this little snippet of css that will override the way the space are rendered in the title (and will thus allow proper wrapping) in either your master page, a separate style sheet or one linked with the master page that you are using (do not edit core.css although)

```
.ms-WPTitle nobr { white-space: normal !important; }
```

The easiest way is to include it inline within your master page, you'll have versioning for your master page if you want to roll back this change and it won't require to create another style sheet and attach it in the master page or load it as an alternate stylesheet.

In the relevant master page, at the end of the head tag, add this style overriding

```
<head>
<!-- ootb head content kept above -->
<style type="text/css">
  .ms-WPTitle nobr { white-space: normal !important; }
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank Francois. I will try it and will provide feedback.

Comment: Glad it helped ! Don't know your SharePoint knowledge but don't forget to publish your master page if you change it, otherwise the regular users won't see your changes :) Cheers.